# Font size is much smaller than normal

Tags: fonts, gimp, kolourpaint

In using the text tool in KolourPaint and Gimp, the font that I type in is way smaller than it should be.
The image is 1377 x 2448. Dot for dot is checked under View.

And View is Zoom 25%.

In this pic the font is in the upper left hand corner.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The font size is the font size in the final image, before the zoom factor is applied. So at 25% zoom a 18px font is rendered as 4.5 pixels high (and even less so in practice form common characters).